# TimePickerDialog : Clicking "Cancel" button calls onTimeSet() method

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I use `TimePickerDialog` with `onTimeSet()` method. I have added a `cancel` button with `onClickListener`.
My problem is that when I click `cancel` button, onTimeSet() method is called. Why is it? Any way to solve this issue?

```
// Create timePicker and set listener
timeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


        };

    timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(RS_CreateTripActivity.this,
                timeListener, hour, min, false);
    timePicker.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    timePicker.setCancelable(false);

    // Set negative button click listener
    timePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        datePicker.dismiss();
        }
});
```

I tried by setting `positive` button with `onClickListener` but in that case I could not get time selected by user. If any one tells me how to get time within `onClickListener`, then it would also solve my problem.

Comment: It first enters `onClick` method and then `onTimeSet`. Thus, used a boolean variable to check if it entered `onClick` method. And it did, then don't execute any code in `onTimeSet` method.

Comment: Please find running solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724781/timepickerdialog-cancel-button/47043247#47043247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the DatePickerDialog and the TimePickerDialog (Issue #34833). You could use a counter as a work-around to get rid of this issue.
Pls. refer to : [Date Picker with cancel option in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932272/date-picker-with-cancel-option-in-android)

Comment: Did you see the issue mentioned in 34833 ?

Comment: Please find running solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724781/timepickerdialog-cancel-button/47043247#47043247

Answer (score 2):

You have to used this way.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;
                    time = ""+mHour+":"+mMinute;

           }
    };



@Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            TimePickerDialog myTime = new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, h, m, false);
            myTime(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                //your cancel task.
            }
            );//For cancel button

        return myTime; //Return the dialog
        break;
        return null;
    }
```

It is work like charm.

Comment: I don't extend `DialogFragment`. Will the `onCreateDialog` method work then? Is `TIME_DIALOG_ID`, your variable or declared in SDK?

Comment: it is declary inbuilt in sdk so what is problem?